# Store sticky post's ids in a transient

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, pre-get-posts, sticky-post, transient

I'm developing a theme that has a featured posts section before the main loop of posts. Cool and fresh, right?:) All sticky posts with a featured image in place must be displayed in that section and excluded from the main loop. Easy peasy. Doing my research, I stumbled upon a [pretty old article](https://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/) on the matter that I found very useful. It advocates not to use `query_posts`, which I did before, and offers a more elegant approach instead:

```
    /**
    * Filter the home page posts, and remove any featured post ID's from it. Hooked
    * onto the 'pre_get_posts' action, this changes the parameters of the query
    * before it gets any posts.
    *
    * @global array $featured_post_id
    * @param WP_Query $query
    * @return WP_Query Possibly modified WP_query
    */
    function itheme2_home_posts( $query = false ) {

      // Bail if not home, not a query, not main query, or no featured posts
      if ( ! is_home() || ! is_a( $query, 'WP_Query' ) || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! itheme2_featuring_posts() )
      return;

      // Exclude featured posts from the main query
      $query->set( 'post__not_in', itheme2_featuring_posts() );

      // Note the we aren't returning anything.
      // 'pre_get_posts' is a byref action; we're modifying the query directly.
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'itheme2_home_posts' );

    /**
    * Test to see if any posts meet our conditions for featuring posts.
    * Current conditions are:
    *
    * - sticky posts
    * - with featured thumbnails
    *
    * We store the results of the loop in a transient, to prevent running this
    * extra query on every page load. The results are an array of post ID's that
    * match the result above. This gives us a quick way to loop through featured
    * posts again later without needing to query additional times later.
    */
    function itheme2_featuring_posts() {
      if ( false === ( $featured_post_ids = get_transient( 'featured_post_ids' ) ) ) {

        // Proceed only if sticky posts exist.
        if ( get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) {

          $featured_args = array(
            'post__in'      => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'no_found_rows' => true
          );

          // The Featured Posts query.
          $featured = new WP_Query( $featured_args );

          // Proceed only if published posts with thumbnails exist
          if ( $featured->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $featured->have_posts() ) {
              $featured->the_post();
              if ( has_post_thumbnail( $featured->post->ID ) ) {
                $featured_post_ids[] = $featured->post->ID;
              }
            }

            set_transient( 'featured_post_ids', $featured_post_ids );
          }
        }
      }

      // Return the post ID's, either from the cache, or from the loop
      return $featured_post_ids;
    }
```

Everything works great except the transients. I can't figure out how to reset the transient if sticky_posts has been updated. Probably use the `updated_option` hook? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
add_action('update_option_sticky_posts', function( $old_value, $value ) {
         $featured_args = array(
            'post__in'      => $value,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'no_found_rows' => true
          );

          // The Featured Posts query.
          $featured = new WP_Query( $featured_args );

          // Proceed only if published posts with thumbnails exist
          if ( $featured->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $featured->have_posts() ) {
              $featured->the_post();
              if ( has_post_thumbnail( $featured->post->ID ) ) {
                $featured_post_ids[] = $featured->post->ID;
              }
            }

            set_transient( 'featured_post_ids', $featured_post_ids );
          }
}, 10, 2);
```

I suppose you have the post IDs on the `sticky_posts` option that's why you are querying with that in the `WP_Query`

Comment: I'm not sure how I can integrate your solution in my existing code. Could you explain, please?

Comment: @Baltar Ofcource If I understand correctly the `sticky_posts` options has the sticky post you want with one of the following formats (array(1,2,3) or "1,2,3"). This is why I monitoring the changes on this options by hooking the action `update_option_{sticky_posts}` You can now have the new values every time you update the option in the `$value`  parameter of the action. The only now step was to loop and update the transient the same way you did it. Tell me if I understand it wrong.

Comment: You got it right, your solution makes sense and works. Thanks!

Comment: There is, however, one scenario in which it will not work as expected.  When you go from `n` sticky posts (with a transient in place) to `zero`, the transient will still have some posts in it, strangely even not the ones you've just un-sticked. I found that deleting the transient if `$value` is empty in your answer fixes the issue. If you confirm and agree with the solution, I'd appreciate if you edit your answer. @Drupalizeme

Comment: @Baltar This will have the same effect as if you initialize the ‘$featured_post_ids’ as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class offers a parameter to include/exclude sticky posts. There's no need to store their IDs anywhere. Just create a new query, and output the sticky posts that have a featured image:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $sticky ) );
```

Now, you can create another loop and exclude the sticky posts:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
```

You can also set the `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to ignore the sticky posts in your loop.

That's all you need.

Comment: I'm excluding sticky posts from the main loop, so new WP_Query is not an option here.